# Mandelbrot displays unprecisely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fractals, mandelbrot

I am trying to visualize the Mandelbrot set using UnityEngine and C#. What I have right now does not look completely wrong but also not right. The Circular shapes for example are very blurred out. Why is that?

[image]

Here is the C sharp code I use:

```cs
    public void CalcValues(int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                C c = new C(mapWidthDefault(width - i - 1), mapHeightDefault(j));
    
                C z = new C(0, 0);
    
                for (int k = 0; k < iterations; k++)
                {
                    z = z * z + c;
                    if (z.abs > upperbound)
                    {
                        pixels[i + j * width] = Color.white;
                        goto end;
                    }
                }
                pixels[i + j * width] = Color.black;
                // Debug.Log(c + ",   " + z + " " + z.abs);
                end:;
            }
        }
        texture.SetPixels(pixels);
        texture.Apply();
    }
    
    private float mapWidthDefault(float x)
    {
        return map(x, 0, width, -3.516f, 1.516f);
    }
    
    private float mapHeightDefault(float x)
    {
        return map(x, 0, height, -1.5f, 1.5f);
    }
    
    private float map(float x, float a1, float a2, float b1, float b2)
    {
        return (x - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1) + b1;
    }
```

The values I use:

iterations: 10
upperBound: 10
width: 800
height: 450

The only setting I changed for my Texture2D is that I set filterMode to bilinear to remove blur.

and here is my C class:

```cs
public class C
    {
        public readonly double Re;
        public readonly double Im;
        public readonly double abs;

        public C(double real, double imaginary)
        {
            this.Re = real;
            this.Im = imaginary;
            this.abs = Re * Re + Im * Im; // squared abs
        }

        public static C operator +(C c1, C c2)
        {
            return new C(c1.Re + c2.Re, c1.Im + c2.Im);
        }

        public static C operator *(C c1, C c2)
        {
            return new C(c1.Re * c2.Re - c1.Im * c2.Im,
                c1.Re * c2.Im + c1.Im * c2.Re);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is C))
                return false;
            return ((C)obj).Re == Re && ((C)obj).Im == Im;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what are the settings on your texture?

Comment: Filter Mode bilinear is the only Setting I set.

Comment: why would you not use point?

Comment: Set iterations=100, rather than just 10.

Comment: I hoped it might get less blurry when using bilinear. 
When I use more interations all z overflow to Infinitiy or NaN

Comment: When I switch your code to use `System.Numeric.Complex` it produces values of `c` that are entirely outside the expected range. What is your `C` class doing?

Comment: Because of `if (z.abs > upperbound) ...` it will not overflow for large iteration numbers.

Comment: Also, you can set the `upperbound = 2`. See: [Plotting algorithms for the Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotting_algorithms_for_the_Mandelbrot_set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration limit of `10` will only produce a crude image. At the base level, I suggest you use `100` and much greater at deeper levels of zoom.

Also the upper bound of `10` wastes processing time, since it is known that the value will eventually escape when it is `> 2`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) states

> In other words, the absolute value of ***z<sub>n</sub>*** must remain at or below `2` for `c` to be in the Mandelbrot set and if that absolute value exceeds `2`, the sequence will escape to infinity.

As far as filtering the image goes, that's the last thing you should think about, for presentation.